# how to write list code that links a picture with a correct word?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, unity-game-engine

im trying to make a picture game quiz- the core mechanic of the game is to choose the correct picture out of the 4 choices to match with the given word. i have been experimenting with using array/list to pair up the picture with a word. but dont know how. need a hero to help mee please!! im very new to unity so i just need a guide :)

```
public class listtest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> vp = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<string> word = new List<string>();
}
```

the final result perhaps should at least show the pair matching.

Comment: **Dictionary<TKey,TValue>** can help you to pair string and picture. But a good approach is to create a **Class** for your object.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your lists are in the correct order and have the exact same size you could do

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> ImageByString = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
public Dictionary<GameObject, string> StringByImage = new Dictionary<GameObject, string>();

private void Start()
{
    // at least have an "emergency" check and use the smaller list count
    var count = Mathf.Min(vp.Count, word.Count);

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ImageByString.Add(word[i], vp[i]);
        StringByImage.Add(vp[i], word[i]);
    }
}
```

or using Linq

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void Start()
{
    ImageByString = word.Zip(vp, (k, v) => new {k, v}).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
    StringByImage = vp.Zip(word, (k, v) => new {k, v}).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
}
```

---

However this will not show up in the Unity Inspector. If you are trying to achieve that you should rather implement your own class like

```
[Serializable]
public class WordImagePair
{
    public string word;
    public GameObject vp;
}
```

Then you have to "trust" that all `word` values are unique so you can simply do

```
public List<WordImagePair> pairs = new List<WordImagePair>();
```

Now either use a dictionary again like

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> ImageByString = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
public Dictionary<GameObject, string> StringByImage = new Dictionary<GameObject, string>();

private void Start()
{
    foreach(var pair in pairs)
    {
        ImageByString.Add(pair.word, pair.vp);
        StringByImage.Add(pair.vp, pair.word);
    }
}
```

or again with Linq

```
private void Start()
{
    ImageByString = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.word, p => p.vp);
    StringByImage = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.vp, P => p.word);
}
```

or later use Linq directly in order to access images like

```
public GameObject ImageByString(string word)
{
    var output = pairs.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.word, word));

    if(output == null)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "No Image with word=\"{0}\" found!", word);
    }

    return output;
}

public string StringByImage(GameObject vp)
{
    var output = pairs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.vp == vp);

    if(output == null)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "No word for given GameObject {0} found!", vp.name);
    }

    return output;
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*